# Count Most Frequent Values for Key in Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, count

I have a Pandas Dataframe where the column 'items' is a dictionary and shows per transaction which products have been bought:

```
data = {'price':[40, 15, 10, 2],
    'items': ["{'product': 'Product1', 'quantity': 4, 'product': 'Product2', 'quantity': 1}", "{'product': 'Product2', 'quantity': 1, 'product': 'Product3', 'quantity': 1,'product': 'Product1', 'quantity': 1}", "{'product': 'Product1', 'quantity': 4}", "{'product': 'Product3', 'quantity': 1, 'product': 'Product1', 'quantity': 1}"]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['price', 'items'])
```

[image]

I want to find out which products have been bought most. In this case the result should look like:

```
Product1: 4
Product2: 2
```

How can I count the most frequent values of the key 'product' within the column 'items'?

Comment: Your dict is invalid since duplicated key

Comment: was about to say that. this is the case with both `product` and `quantity` keys

Comment: I see, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a `namedtuple` (from the built-in `collections` package).
First, define a named tuple called Record create a list of these:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd

Record = namedtuple('Record', 'price product quantity')

records = [
    Record(40, 'Product1', 4), Record(40, 'Product2', 1),
    Record(15, 'Product2', 1), Record(15, 'Product3', 1), Record(15, 'Product1', 1),
    Record(10, 'Product1', 4),
    Record( 2, 'Product3', 1), Record(2, 'Product1', 1),]
```

Second, create the data frame, and use groupby to compute number of each product:

```
# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(records)

# compute summary statistic
df = df.groupby('product')['quantity'].sum()
print(df)

product
Product1    10
Product2     2
Product3     2
Name: quantity, dtype: int64
```

I did not match your expected results.  Sorry if I misunderstood your data and/or question.